# A weird symbol the Cullens had on them

Tags: twilight

In the movie Edward, Emmett and Jasper are wearing matching wristbands with a symbol and Rosalie and Alice are wearing the same symbol on necklaces, what is the significance of these items?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the Cullen Crest

[image]

> the lion represents strength and ferocity, which is a characteristic of the vampires. The hand is faith and sincerity, showing that the Cullens are loyal to each other. The trefoil at the bottom is perpetuality, which is lasting forever, showing the vampires' inability to die naturally

From [The Director's Notebook: The Story of How We Made the Movie](http://twilightsaga.wikia.com/wiki/Twilight:_Director%27s_Notebook)